# Microsoft ODBC For Oracle with TransactionScope

Tags: vb.net, oracle, transactions

I use Microsoft ODBC For Oracle, and process a distributed transaction with TransactionScope, but, the code throws a error: ERROR [HYC00][ORACLE][ODBC]option not implement, my code is in vb.net.

Here is my code:

```
sub Main()
    dim strConn1 as string = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=server1;UID=user1;PWD=pwd1;"
    dim strConn2 as string = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=server2;UID=user2;PWD=pwd2;"
    try
        using scope as new TransactionScope()
            using conn1 as new OdbcConnection(strConn1)
                conn1.Open()    'always throws error here
                dim command1 as new OdbcCommand(strSQL1)
                command1.ExecuteNonQuery()
                using conn2 as new OdbcConnection(strConn2)
                    dim command2 as new OdbcCommand(strSQL2)
                    command2.ExecuteNonQuery()
                end using
            end using
            scope.Complete()
        end using
    catch
    end try
end sub
```

who can tell me why, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be your problem, but I never use the Microsoft Oracle driver. I always use the Oracle driver, also known as the Oracle Instant Client. You can [get it here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html).

Comment: Microsoft ODBC for Oracle is bad news. Avoid it like the plague. The long list of reasons is out of scope for this space, but I'll mention the first one here: it is not supported for any version of Oracle later than 8i.

Comment: I've had way too many bad experiences with Microsoft's driver so I don't even bother with it anymore. I was having problems with it when I WAS using 8i.

Comment: Same here. Complete lack of Unicode support, nonstandard support for procedures returning resultsets, *very* weird handling of fetch errors from server side cursors, etc. Its only advantage was that unlike its successors, it didn't force me to  use WCHAR for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific. Like where is connection object. Please put the entire class file code. It seems some problem with connection object. Paste the entire code so that we can provide you exact solution